# How to create a Linked Server of Azure SQL Database with MFA in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, azure, linked-server

I am trying to create a linked server in SQL Server 2017.
The server I want to connect to remotely is an Azure SQL Database Server with Active Directory - Universal with MFA support authentication.

[image]

I tried creating it both ways (SQL Server and Other data source) with correct credentials and catalog information.
But every time it says, authentication failed. with an additional message **"Invalid authorization specification (Error: 7399)".**

Can anybody help?

Comment: I doubt very much if you can connect to a linked server with MFA. What type of security did you pick? (that would be your authorization specification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, we cannot create a linked server to Azure SQL DB with MFA authentication type.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/sql-database/sql-database-ssms-mfa-authentication?toc=/azure/sql-data-warehouse/toc.json&view=azuremgmthdinsight-2.0.5) is the link to MS Docs for more info.

Comment: Is there any update regarding that? I need to make a link to sql server which uses MFA. by the way in your link there is nothing mentioned about link server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Reference:

1. [How to create a linked server to an Azure SQL database](https://www.sqlshack.com/create-linked-server-azure-sql-database/).
2. [Configure multi-factor authentication for SQL Server Management Studio and Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-ssms-mfa-authentication-configure)

Hope this helps.