# SQL Server create linked server with Dataverse (using TDS)

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dataverse

We are trying to create an linked server from our on-prem SQL with Dataverse (Dynamics CRM Online) database (that uses TDS - Tubular Data Stream), but we are unable to pass an authentication that works.

When we try to access Dataverse (Dynamics CRM Online) database using TDS (Tubular Data Stream), [we accomplished it with success](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/dataverse-sql-query) using the following authentication:
[SQL authentication using and account with MFA (multi factor authentication) active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8cvo.png)
Or using:
[SQL authentication using and account without MFA active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7qSv.png)

But we are unable to create linked server, we already tried multiple options of authentication:

- Example 1:
  -General > Server Type > SQL Server
  -Security > For a login not defined in the list above, connections will: > Be made using this security context > (used an user that didn't need MFA (multi factor authentication) that worked connecting to Dataverse SQL and making some queries)
  Error obtained:
  [image: error]
- Example 2:
  -General > Server Type > SQL Server
  -Security > For a login not defined in the list above, connections will: > Be made using this
  (We got the same error showed above)

We tried to create linked server with multiple authentication options, but with no success.
We found a conector from a 3rd party company that allow "Connect to Microsoft Dataverse Data as a Linked Server", but Microsoft should allow this from OOTB functionality, we are talking of only Microsoft applications here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Linked Server of Azure SQL Database with MFA in SQL Server 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54550239/how-to-create-a-linked-server-of-azure-sql-database-with-mfa-in-sql-server-2017)

Comment: We tried @siggemannen but with no success. We think it's because the authentication used by the method you shared is not the 'Azure Active Directory - Univeral with MFA'.  
 The error is the same that we shown in the question.